# how do i put my output into a session

Tags: php, forms, session, post

i have this code that receive form input example below code my problem is how do i put this output into session so even when i refress or reopen this page i we still have my output
 code:

```
   session_start();
  if (isset($_POST["chedit"]))
       {
          $text = $_POST["text"];
          $mumu = $_POST["edit"];
            $_SESSION["text"] = $text;

            $_SESSION["mumu"] = $mumu;

            $text = $_SESSION["text"];

            $mumu = $_SESSION["mumu"];

            echo $text;

            echo $mumu;

            }
```

every thing is working fine but if i try to reopen this page i got my recent output lost can any fixed this? Big thanks

Comment: What is the output you get, what errors do you get? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just trying to keep any submited output for long time even when the page is reopen or refress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way `$_POST['text]` and `$_POST['edit']` will be stored in `$_SESSION['text']` and `$_SESSION['mumu']` and always printed:

```
<?php  
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["chedit"]))
{
    $text = $_POST["text"];
    $mumu = $_POST["edit"];
    $_SESSION["text"] = $text;
    $_SESSION["mumu"] = $mumu;
}
if (isset($_SESSION["text"]) && isset($_SESSION["mumu"]))
{
    echo '<p>' . $_SESSION["text"];
    echo '<p>' . $_SESSION["mumu"];
}
?>
```

But of course you can use that variables however you want. They will be stored as long as you don't close the navigator.

Comment: To follow the OP style I would change your output to `$text = $_SESSION["text"]; echo '<p>' . $text;`